# Is there a way to load a large text file into kdb line by line?

Tags: kdb

Is there a way to load a large text file (150GB+) into kdb, line by line, and save a fixed number of the lines into one table?

I have tried using the size limiting argument in read0, but as each line of the text file is of different size I was not able to get a complete row every time.

Answer (score 4):

You can do so with the help of .Q.fs. This will read the file in cunks. See http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/loading-from-large-files/ for moe information / examples.